# How does SSH authentication works?

Tags: ssh

My question is based on this scenario: `serverA`, `serverB`, `user1`, and `user2`. Both users are present on both the servers.

`user1` on `serverA` has SSH keypairs generated and the public key copied to the `authorized_keys` file on `serverB`.

`user2` on `serverA` has no SSH key pairs generated and also on `serverB`.

`user1` logs into `serverA`. `user1` tries to SSH to `serverB` as `user2` (`ssh user2@serverb`) and it works fine, no password asked.

My question is this. How does this work? `user2` has no public keys on `serverB`. I always thought that SSH authenticates the user trying to login.
Does this mean that SSH on `serverB` authenticates the currently logged in `user1` on `serverA`?

Comment: The scenario you describe should not behave in this way. I think your missing something. Read the man page for ssh (noting the effect of '-v') and your sshd log files.

Comment: Do user1 and user2 have the same home directory on Server B?

Comment: I recreated this scenario on redhat labs moments ago ---

vms: workstation and servera----

user1: 'student' on workstation and also on servera. Pub key for student user copied to .rht_authorised key on servera-----

user2: 'joel' created only on servera. No SSH keys exists on workstation or servera.----

logged in from [student@workstation # ssh joel@servera] Logged in fine and no password was prompted for. 

maybe I a missing something here in sshd config but I am not able to point exactly to that directive that allows this behavior.

Comment: @roaima. No they dont have the same home directory.. You can see my above scenario that I recreated

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vv" option to print debugging info, then [edit] your question to include the debugging output. That should show how the client is authenticating.

Comment: I don't see any scenario in your question

Comment: please edit your post and unify **users** (user1/user2 in post vs student/joel in comment) and **host** (servera/serverb in post vs workstation/servera in comment)

Comment: Does user2 have a password set at all? If the password for user2 is blank and password authentication is enabled, anyone can get in from anywhere.

Comment: There is an automated process that you are unaware of running in the background, which is copying keys to servers; possibly it is Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound right at all. Are you using OpenSSH? Or some other ssh implementation?

Going back to your question of how it works, it is as you expect (simplified):

- Connect to remote system.
- Pass username.
- Remote system verifies user exists and requests key if key auth is configured.
- Checks user HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys exists
- Checks entries in authorized_keys one by one until one works, or none left.
- If matching key is found, authentication succeeds.

It is all based upon the keys in the destination user ~.ssh/authorized_keys file.
If there is no such file/key, something is very broken.

Comment: It's both. Its a question on the ssh implementation being used, and its a simplifies answer to the question of how the key based authentication works -- stripped down to just the essentials to answer in this context.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

In comments, you mentioned `.rht_authorised key`.

The default per-user authorized key file should be `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` where `~` refers to the user's home directory. If `.rht_authorised` is used at all, that means a non-default OpenSSH configuration is being used.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` can define (using the `AuthorizedKeysFile` keyword) a different location (or multiple locations) for the authorized key file: if it's defined as an absolute path and no tokens like `%h`, `%u` or `%U` are used in the definition, then all users will use the same authorized key file.

In newer OpenSSH versions, there is also an `AuthorizedKeysCommand` keyword, which defines a program or script that will be used to look up public keys when authenticating a user. It is not used by default, but might be used in some hosting or cloud set-ups.

What does `grep -i authorizedkeys /etc/ssh/sshd_config` report?